# What is the meaning of adding a + in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a condition in reactjs that starts with

```
+this.state.isCompleted
```

Why do we write `+` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a forced [conversion](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp) to `number`

```js
const str = '1'
const bool = false
const fail = 'isNan?'

const num = +str
const numBool = +bool
const numFail = +fail

console.log(typeof num, typeof numBool, numFail)
```